# Замена цвета и толщины полилинии Yandex Mapkit

Tags: java, yandexmapkit

Я построил маршрут, и хочу поменять цвет и толщину полилинии построенного маршрута.
Всё что я добился, это замена или толщины или цвета

```
// замена цвета
mapObjects_navi.addPolyline(route.getGeometry()).setStrokeColor(RGB);
// замена толщины
mapObjects_navi.addPolyline(route.getGeometry()).setStrokeWidth(10);
```

Но поменять одновременно оба свойства не могу. У полилинии нет такого. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял как надо сделать

```
@SuppressLint("Range") int RGB = Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0);
PolylineMapObject polyline = mapObjects_navi.addPolyline(route.getGeometry());
polyline.setStrokeColor(RGB);
polyline.setStrokeWidth(12);
```